# How to Quickly Create a Plain Text Table in Office?

Tags: html, emacs, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I'm looking for a method to quickly create a Plain Text Table in the MS Office suite (e.g. a line would be replaced with the dash format "------" ? Creating a standard HTML supported table and then applying a conversion would suffice.

Thanks,
F.

Comment: Wondering the whys of the emacs tag :)

Comment: I know that emacs has some interesting plug-ins that support plain text table generation so I'm hoping that there is a simpler "windows" based conversion tool/method available.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Excel document with the data. That allows you to export the current sheet as HTML (not pretty).

An alternative is to copy the data into the clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>) and use a small program which reads the clipboard as "text/html".